# Elasticsearch Implementation on Cakephp 3

Tags: elasticsearch, cakephp-3.0

I was able to incorporate elasticsearch on cakephp 3 but I lost the ability to save on my database. The add method on the controller creates an index instead of doing both (save to table and create an index in elasticsearch). Followed the instructions from here -  https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/elasticsearch.html.

Any idea on how I can achieve the above?

Thanks.

Adding code from Categories Controller.

```
public function add()
{
    $category = $this->Categories->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $category = $this->Categories->patchEntity($category, $this->request->getData());
        if ($this->Categories->save($category)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The category has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The category could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $this->set(compact('category'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['category']);
}
```

Comment: Maybe show the code from the method in question?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @GregSchmidt! Modified the post to add the missing code.